# Multiple search with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've got some problem in making a search using checkbox.
Basically, I've got some data that has its date of registration, i need to make search by months and retrieve the data according to selected month or months.

I am using php and mysql.

Here I have a simple html:

---

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="1" />January</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="2" />February</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="3" />March</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="4" />April</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="5" />May</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="6" />June</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="7" />July</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="8" />August</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="9" />September</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="10" />October</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="11" />November</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in" value="12" />December</li>
<li><input type="submit" value="Search"></li>
</ul>
```

---

and part of php+mysql code:

```
$search=$_POST["month_in"];

$qry=mysql_query("select * from table where MONTH(dor) like '%{$search}%'");
```

The problem is that above code works only if user checks only one month, but if user checks 2 or more months it retrieves information only for the highest month (i mean if user has checked January, March, April and August it gives the results of August only).

Comment: On a side note, be careful about possible [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that even if a user selects more than one checkbox, the value of the last checkbox selected will be sent back to your php script. If you want to post more than one value in array format, then change the name attribute of your checkboxes from `name="month_in"` to `name="month_in[]"`. So you will receive a numeric array of months.

```
 array(10, 12);

 //fetch and make it a comma separated string using implode() php string function
 $csvSearch = implode(',', $_POST["month_in"]);
 $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(dor, '$csvSearch')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array for `name` attribute for checkboxes

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="1" />January</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="2" />February</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="3" />March</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="4" />April</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="5" />May</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="6" />June</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="7" />July</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="8" />August</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="9" />September</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="10" />October</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="11" />November</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="month_in[]" value="12" />December</li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Search"></li>
    </ul>
```

Use the `IN` keyword to retrieve results

```
$search=$_POST["month_in"];
$search_string = implode(', ', $search);
$qry=mysql_query("select * from table where MONTH(dor) IN ($search_string)");
```

Comment: Your parameters for `implode` are reversed. The glue comes first.

Comment: @JimH. My bad, sleep deprivation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in...`

Comment: It should be `IN ($search_string)`. Also, make sure that `$_POST["month_in"]` is set, otherwise you'll attempt to do `IN ()`, which is not valid.

Comment: Thank you. The answer from **codef0rmer** already works! The problem here I guess was in **IN ($search_string)** like you pointed out.